# Converting Short VBA Code to JQuery for Excel Add-in

Tags: vba, excel, office365api, excel-addins, office-js

I need to do a quick proof-of-concept Excel add-in to show the higher ups for use on iPad and the web. Our desktop Excel workbooks have a lot of cells that the end user can customize to their needs/circumstances. We always include VBA code that allows the user to reset the inputs to the default values that we provide.

For desktop use, I set-up a background worksheet that has a column of cells linked to the input cells via formula and then a column beside of it that contains the default values. A simple loop within the range resets all the cells.

```
For Each cell In Range("Inputs")
    If cell.Formula = "" Then
    Else
        Range(cell.Formula) = cell.Offset(0, 1).Formula
    End If
Next cell
```

If anyone could help help convert this code for use with the JQuery add-in language it would be much appreciated.

I've gotten everything else set-up in VisualStudio, but am having trouble implementing this in JQuery with the new APIs given I'm strictly a VBA guy. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Sorry, are you saying that you have an excel sheet open in the web page, or you have HTML elements, similar to cells, that you want to populate? or are you trying to use JQuery in excel?